# Get ID for SQL command in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am using the chart.js library to create graphs. I can successfully create graphs using individual ID's from users. However, I would like to rewrite my code so that I could extract the user's ID from the URL and generate graph based on that specific ID.

**Here is the code i'm using now to generate the points in the graph:**

```html
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = 21 ORDER BY created_at");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Here is what the page outputs:

```html
[{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-11"},{"bdi":"1","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"5","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"34","date":"2018-07-21"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-22"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-23"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-24"},{"bdi":"2","date":"2018-07-25"},{"bdi":"12","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"3","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"4","date":"2018-07-30"},{"bdi":"11","date":"2018-07-30"}]
```

In this case "21" is specific user. I am familiar with prepared statements, and have attempted rewrite this as a prepared statement.

**Here is my attempt:**

```html
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
 die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);
//query to get data from the table
$sql = sprintf("SELECT treatment_log.bdi, treatment_log.date FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? ORDER BY created_at");

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);   

//execute query
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$results->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Obviously my code doesn't seem to work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);   

//execute query
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

into this:

```
$data = array();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $bdi, $date);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    $data[]['bdi'] = $dbi;
    $data[]['date'] = $date;
}
```

Comment: I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\charts\data.php on line 31

Comment: @James if you find my answer useful, kindly, accept it.